# Looping Through Custom Tax Terms and Displaying All Posts For Each

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, query, taxonomy, terms

I'm using the following code to attempt to loop through each of the terms within my custom taxonomy `category-film` and then output the term name as a heading together with displaying all the custom posts that belong to that term

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( 'category-film' ); ?>

<?php foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

    <?php $posts = new WP_Query( 'post=film&category-film= ' . $term->slug . '&posts_per_page=-1' ); ?>

    <?php if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>        

        <h3><?php echo $term->name; ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php the_field('url'); ?>
        </div>  

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am finding, however, that my code outputs nothing whatsoever.

If I move `<h3><?php echo $term->name; ?></h3>` so that it is *outside* of the loop (but within the `foreach` loop) it outputs the names of the terms fine.

So I imagine the problem must be something to do with the loop itself?

Comment: Do not use `$posts` as a custom variable, it breaks and stuffs up the `$posts` global, rather use something like `$posts_array`

Comment: Also, just a note, your query is very expensive :-)

Comment: thanks @PieterGoosen, I've tried that but unfortunately still having the same issue. I can't seem to output anything in the loop, even if just static content

Comment: You can try something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/195764/31545), just note, this was done for the main query, so you will need to adjust it slightly for a custom query

Comment: @PieterGoosen ah what do you mean by expensive? Ha... is it a bit inefficient?

Comment: Use a proper `tax_query`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your things are laid properly, this code will output 10 posts from `film` CPT, where taxonomy is `category-film` and it will occur each of the term of that particular taxonomy. I'm not aware about your templating, so lay your layout accordingly.

```
<?php
$_terms = get_terms( array('category-film') );

foreach ($_terms as $term) :

    $term_slug = $term->slug;
    $_posts = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type'         => 'film',
                'posts_per_page'    => 10, //important for a PHP memory limit warning
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category-film',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $term_slug,
                    ),
                ),
            ));

    if( $_posts->have_posts() ) :

        echo '<h3>'. $term->name .'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="row">';
        while ( $_posts->have_posts() ) : $_posts->the_post();
        ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'url', true ); ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;

        echo '</div>';

    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

endforeach;
?>
```